# Programming C - fscanf () doesn´t read the whole date, it read only "1 8 2020" instead of "01 08 2020"

Tags: c, file, date, scanf

I will Progg. a simpel C Programm that read birthdate and full name from a file.
i will try it with high level I/O stream.
But i have one problem...i use fscanf() to read the file...
but it not read the full date of the file like this:

*FILE:* (test.txt)

```
01 02 1999 name1 nachname1
08 01 2000 name2 nachname2
10 02 2001 name3 nachname3
```

it just read this:

*OUTPUT OF PROGRAMM:*

```
1 2 1999 name1 nachname1
8 1 2000 name2 nachname2
10 2 2001 name3 nachname3
```

it dont show the `0` at the beginning of the date Number.
Pls check my source Code and tell me what i have done wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
    int main()
    {//   MAIN START
        char name[20],fname[20];
        int day,month,year;
        FILE *fd;
        fd= fopen("test.txt","r");
    // read word by word
    while( fscanf(fd,"%d %d %d %s %s",&month,&day,&year,&name,&fname) != -1) // print till EOF
        {
        printf("\n DATA: %d %d %d %s %s\n",month,day,year,name,fname);
        }
    fclose(fd);
    }//   MAIN END
```

*Here is again my file (test.txt):*

```
01 02 1999 name1 nachname1
08 01 2000 name2 nachname2
10 02 2001 name3 nachname3
```

*And here is again the output of the compiled Programm:*

```
1 2 1999 name1 nachname1
8 1 2000 name2 nachname2
10 2 2001 name3 nachname3
```

compiler: GCC

OS: Linux

Best regards ME :) !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not showing the 0 at the beginning of the data is because you are storing the value as an `int`. When printing an `int` with `%d`, you will never see leading zeros, because 0001 = 1. You would have to read them in as strings in order to get the leading zeros, and then use atoi to get the actual number or use fscanf again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
    {//   MAIN START
        char name[20],fname[20];
        char day[5],month[5],year[5];
        FILE *fd;
        fd= fopen("test.txt","r");
    // read word by word
    while( fscanf(fd,"%s %s %s %s %s",&month,&day,&year,&name,&fname) != -1) // print till EOF
        {
        printf("\n DATA: %s %s %s %s %s\n",month,day,year,name,fname);
        }
    fclose(fd);
    }//   MAIN END
```

Comment: `fscanf(fd,"%s %s %s %s %s",&month,&day,&year,&name,&fname) !=5` makes more sense as `fscanf()` here may return `5,4,3,2,1,0` or `EOF`.  `fscanf(fd,"%4s %4s %4s %19s %19s",&month,&day,&year,&name,&fname) != 5` is even better.

Comment: You can tell `printf()` to include leading zeros from numbers.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with the reads, but the format you are outputting.  Try:

```
 printf("\n DATA: %02d %02d %04d %s %s\n", month, day, year, name, fname);
```

`%02d` will print zero padded integers with a width of 2.